# elementary OS "Suspender"

Tags: system-installation

I'm new in elementary OS. Yesterday, I tried booting from pen drive and it's very nice. Unfortunately, I can't install it because my HDD stopped working.

I left the laptop doing updates in the night and today. When I've gone to see if everything is ok, nothing appears on the screen, I only see the mouse. Maybe the computer went to suspension, and elementary OS could not start from there.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you updating while working from the live USB pendrive itself? Or have you updated it after installing to your HDD? Or have you installed it to another pendrive? (I assume the first one because you said your HDD is not working-still mention it clearly)
 If you are updating from the pendrive then it is of no use because when you shutdown, restart the computer and boot again from the *live USB pendrive* then *all the updates will be gone* and the system will be like a fresh un-updated elementary OS. Please clarify it in your question or here in the comments.

Comment: I'm working from liveUSB. I create a usb with the "Universal USB Installer" and create to a persistent partion with 4gb. the update doesn't work with that? So maybe is better install the elementary os from this liveUSB to another usb and use that second one?

Comment: The persistent partition is only for storing files like documents etc. when you need to use the pendrive in emergency. Trust me-these days it is not reliable(so basically useless and waste of pendrive space). A system update doesn't save any updated files on the pendrive. Why? Because the pendrive (in Unetbootin) is made to work like a CD- only reading data is allowed not writing(i.e. changing or saving data) in it. So you need to install it in the computer or another pendrive/harddrive to save the updates.

Comment: So from that liveUSB if i chose the option "Install OS", can i chose another pendrive and install there or only let me chose internal HDD drive?

Comment: Yes you can install in another pendrive. Just make sure that you install the bootloader in that pendrive as well. And also choose a pendrive of large enough space so you can install any apps you need later. I recommend 16 GB.

Comment: If i install directly from liveUSB don't install automatically the bootloader? Have some tutorial that you recommend me to install the bootloader?

Comment: By default the bootloader is installed in the HDD but in your case for installing in a pendrive that will be unwise. [Here](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/installubuntutousbdrive.html&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=943&ts=1440071452&sig=APONPFmXpseWfKMaJAT4gwW0CM-ssPa9sA) is a detailed guide(with video) explaining the procedure. The procedure is exactly same for Elementary OS.

Comment: Hey @Antonio if I helped then do tick that green check-mark just beside my answer. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I will try and then i post the result.

Comment: Hello. I try like the movie and work perfect for me.  about the initial problem, isn't the suspension but is the display, in power options was to turn off display past 15min of inactivity, and i turn it off. And now, work perfectly. Now i only need to increase my skills in linux...

Comment: Glad I could help you @Antonio. And thanks for the green-check-mark o my answer. It means a lot to me. Have a nice day and welcome to the world of Linux! Hope you enjoy it!

Comment: Install elementary OS in persistent usb have no swap partition.  That's the reason that you cannot go to suspend mode.